# How to install ruby on rails in windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Getting error while trying to install Ruby on Rails like below command

```
Praveen@PraveenLaptop MINGW64 ~
$ gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

> ERROR:  Error installing rails:
>
> ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> current directory: C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/nio4r-2.2.0/ext/ni                                                                                                                o4r
>
> C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20180224-8176-ibolzo.rb extconf.rb
>
> current directory: C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/nio4r-2.2.0/ext/nio4r
>   make "DESTDIR=" clean
>   'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> current directory: C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/nio4r-2.2.0/ext/nio4r
>   make "DESTDIR="
>   'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> make failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/nio4r-                                                                                                                2.2.0 for inspection.
>   Results logged to C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.5.0                                                                                                                /nio4r-2.2.0/gem_make.out
>   Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
>   Building native extensions. This could take a while...

Can anyone figure out what is the problem of getting this error

Comment: Do you have Ruby development kit installed?

Comment: Yes I have installed. Actually I followed this http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/installing-rails-5-windows

Comment: @PRAVEENKUMAR including everything here? "Now we need to make the DevKit tools available to Ruby."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow those steps, actually, I have installed Ruby on Rails to many windows machine using these steps.

**Step 1:** Download [Git BASH](https://gitforwindows.org/) as the BASH emulation behaves just like the "git" command in LINUX and UNIX environments.

**Step 1.1:** Download and install latest NodeJS from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and check the NodeJS version

```
$ node -v
#=> v6.11.5 # or something like this
```

**Step 2:** Download the ruby latest version [here](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) and install it in your directory. Check the Ruby version

```
$ ruby -v
#=> ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x64-mingw32]
# or something like this
```

**Step 3:** Download Devkit [here](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) take the suitable one for matching your windows bit like 32 or 64 bit

**Step 4:** Create a devkit folder inside Ruby directory that means where created a default directory after installing ruby software, something like this `disk (:C) or (:D)/Ruby25/devkit/`

**Step 5:** Extract the DevKit file inside the `devkit` folder

**Step 6:** Open your GIT BASH inside the devkit folder and run this two commands

```
$ ruby dk.rb init
$ ruby dk.rb install
```

if above command running properly then done.

**Step 7:** Now you can run rails command for installing inside ruby folder

```
 $ gem install rails
```

**Step 8:** Check the Rails version

```
 $ rails -v
 #=> Rails 5.0.6
```

if till now all are steps is ok? that's it, now run rails command and create a rails project, like

```
$ rails new project
 create
    create  README.md
    create  Rakefile
    create  config.ru
    create  .gitignore
    create  Gemfile
    create  app
    create  app/assets/config/manifest.js
    ............
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

What the error is saying is that it can't find `make`. If you have MSYS2 already installed, make sure you add the location where MSYS2 is installed is in your `PATH` environment variable.

Alternatively, you can run `ridk install` if you do not have (or want to reinstal) MSYS2 so that it can be used by ruby.