# Error installing rails failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm trying to Install Rails with this guide:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

And I keep getting this error (below).

Any suggestion?

I'm working on the cmd (windows 8).

(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

I'm typing: `ruby -v`

And then I get: `ruby 2.4.3p205 (2017-12-14 revision 61247) [x64-mingw32]`

I'm typing: `sqlite3 --version`

And then I get: `3.22.0 2018-01-22 18:45:57 0c55d179733b46d8d0ba4d88e01a25e10677046ee3da1d5b1581e
86726f2171d`

I'm typing: `gem install rails`

And then I get:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/websocket-driver-0
.6.5/ext/websocket-driver
C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20180318-5748-xd7wo5.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.6.5
/ext/websocket-driver
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.6.5
/ext/websocket-driver
make "DESTDIR="
generating websocket_mask-x64-mingw32.def
make: *** No rule to make target `/C/Ruby24-x64/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby.h', need
ed by `websocket_mask.o'.  Stop.

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/websoc
ket-driver-0.6.5 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.4.0
/websocket-driver-0.6.5/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Follow these steps for installing Rails in windows https://stackoverflow.com/a/48970147/4172515

Comment: I'm trying your guide :)
I already have nodejs, how do I make the MINGW64 to get the command "node -v"?

Comment: now I'm getting "command not found"
or if I try "./node -v" -> "no such file or directory"

Comment: It will be just `node -v`, to your command prompt you can write just `node -v` after installing the latest `NodeJS`

Answer (score 2):

I just had exactly the same problem with websocket-driver native extension (Windows 10) with exact the same error message:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `/C/Ruby24-x64/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby.h', need
ed by `websocket_mask.o'.  Stop.

make failed, exit code 2
```

The solution in my case was to pay attention during "MSYS2-Devkit" installation to chose the option **"3"** (MSYS2 and MINGW development toolchain)

After that "bundle install" in my case installed and compiled all dependencies of a rails project

Answer (score 0):

Try using rvm using Cygwin. It should help solve ruby version issues.

see https://rvm.io/rvm/install

Comment: are you sure it's a version issues?

Comment: no i'm not sure, but it does seem like some kind of problem with your installation.  Those kind of errors indicate your system may not have the required libraries or that your $PATH doesn't include the location to binaries needed to build the gem.  My suggestion was that using a version manager like RVM may help handle configurations needed to build rails on your system.

Comment: see https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/#rubyinstaller