# rails -v, command just hangs locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-line-interface

I am trying to use the rails cli to scaffold a throwaway app, but I the command is just 'hanging' for me. For instance, I cannot even see what version of rails I have installed:

```
$ rails -v
...
...
...
```

The `...` is suppose to indicate the indefinite incompletion of the command.

Has anyone come across this problem before?

Comment: Purge your rails installation, and install rails again.

Comment: See this for complete [Ruby on Rails install](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48970147/4172515)