# Installing rails: 'make' is not recognized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm installing rails on Windows 10 but I'm facing this error:

> Building native extensions. This could take a while...
>   ERROR:  Error installing rails:
>           ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> current directory: C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/nio4r-2.5.2/ext/nio4r
>   C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20200307-5848-1c7k9o0.rb extconf.rb
>
> current directory: C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/nio4r-2.5.2/ext/nio4r
>   make "DESTDIR=" clean
>   'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> current directory: C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/nio4r-2.5.2/ext/nio4r
>   make "DESTDIR="
>   'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> make failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/nio4r-2.5.2 for inspection.
>   Results logged to C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.5.0/nio4r-2.5.2/gem_make.out

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48963291/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-in-windows?rq=1